# Computed Line-Height CSS is much larger than element spec

Tags: html, css

I have a row of 4 buttons (2 of them `a href` and the other 2 `btn`) where the A-Link Buttons have text slightly higher than the real Buttons.

I found that this problem can be corrected by removing the `line-height = 1.3` element spec on the A-Link Buttons. To verify that the Line-Height matches that of the real buttons, I looked at the **Computed** values of `line-height` on all 4 elements.

But the Computed value is much higher (`20.8px` or `24px`) than the values I tweak (`1.3px` or `1.5px`). Why is that? It's not like an overridden value where a single value matches the element spec's value. So how do I verify that the final vertical alignment of the text in the buttons is the same across all 4 elements?

[image]

Comment: you can use  `!important` like `line-height:1.3 !important`.

Comment: 1.3 doesn't mean 1.3px but 1.3xfont-size value. If you want pixel value you need to set it as pixel value